# How to store Custom claims to User Store, generated in CustomJWTGenerator Class

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have to store custom claims in User database (IS DB) after generating it in "CustomJWTGenerator " class. Do we have any admin API which stores custom claims in IS DB ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these claims a predefined set of claims ? or are they dynamically generated ?

Comment: These are dynamic claims